# bash requesting password on every invocation of sudo

Tags: bash, sudo

Within a single bash session I am repeatedly re-running a command prefixed by sudo. Typically the password should be requested once and then cached. However, the present behavior is that the password is requested each time.

I opened another bash window and the same behavior is observed.

What may be causing that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [Shawn J Goff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2180/shawn-j-goff) answered this particular quirk in another question that was the reverse of this one. The answer is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/forcing-sudo-to-prompt-for-a-password), and as follows:

> From `man sudoers`:
>
> **timestamp_timeout**
>
> Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask for a passwd
>   again. The timeout may include a fractional component if minute
>   granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5. The default is 5. Set
>   this to 0 to always prompt for a password. If set to a value less than
>   0 the user's timestamp will never expire. This can be used to allow
>   users to create or delete their own timestamps via sudo -v and sudo -k
>   respectively.

Comment: Why would the behavior spontaneously change?  I had not touched sudoers.

Comment: That, I don't know that I can answer. Of course, any person or process executing with su or root privilege would be able to modify sudoers, including a process invoked during install, but I honestly can't think of an application that would make a change to force you to enter your password every single time, other than a potential keylogger?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command at the beginning of a session in bash on a Macintosh. It's great if I plan to use multiple commands that need sudoer access. All commands typed after this process will be executed as root.

sudo -s

Example:
Last login: Tue Jun  2 13:38:19 on ttys000
HostName:~ UserName$ sudo -s
Password:
bash-3.2# whoami
root
bash-3.2#